# which paper to take that would best fit to becoming a data scientist?

Tags: data-structures, data-compression, databases, data-mining, data-sets

My name is Webber from Auckland, New Zealand. I am currently in my second year studying the bachelor of computer and information science. I have chosen to do a double major in computational intelligence and analytics. My goal is to become a data scientist after graduation. I am currently trying to decide which paper to take for the following semester, the options are "physical database design" and "Data structures and algorithms" (I have attached the following images of the paper descriptor for both courses).

My question is, which paper should I choose for the next semester that would be best fit for my goal to becoming a data scientist?

Thank you in advance and I look forward to hearing from you.

Regards
Webber
Inline image 1Inline image 2Inline image 3

Comment: Welcome to CS.SE!  Unfortunately this question isn't a good fit here.  We prefer questions that have objectively correct answers that will be useful both to the asker and others who have the same question in the future. What is or is not a suitable topic for study is very much a matter of opinion and depends crucially on the interests and skills of the person who will be doing the work and the support that will be available to them.